# Query and Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attemtping to join two tables together, here is what I have for my join:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NM, TABLE2.CD
from TABLE1 FULL JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PID
WHERE (TABLE2.CD = 'P1' or TABLE2.CD is null)
```

Here is my problem. If TABLE2 has no records where CD = "P1" then it doesn't display any records from TABLE1 for that match. What am I missing?

I appreciate your help.

This is using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Run the query that I have mentioned in answer

Answer (score 2):

Try a [LEFT JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> Use a LEFT JOIN operation to create a left outer join. Left outer
>   joins include all of the records from the first (left) of two tables,
>   even if there are no matching values for records in the second (right)
>   table.

```
SELECT TABLE1.NM, TABLE2.CD
from STU LEFT JOIN CON ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PID
WHERE (TABLE2.CD = 'P1' or TABLE2.CD is null)
```

[image]

<sup>Image from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins</sup>

Comment: I got my original post wrong, could you re-reply? THanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `LEFT JOIN` and put the condition in the `ON` clause instead of your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT TABLE1.NM, ISNULL(TABLE2.CD,'')
from TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PID AND TABLE2.CD = 'P1'
```

Comment: I made a mistake. STU was supposed read TABLE1 and CON was supposed to be read TABLE2 in my original post above.

Comment: I fixed the above post. Could you possibly reply again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TABLE1.NM, TABLE2.CD
from STU FULL LEFT JOIN CON ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PID
WHERE TABLE2.CD = 'P1'
```

Comment: I got my original post wrong. Could you re-do for me? Thanks.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little bit what a full left join does?